# How to ensure message integrity for ciphers created via RSA algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa, integrity

In order to send a message over an unsecured channel I have to first encrypt the data using the RSA algorithm. The implementation I use is the `javax.crypto.Cipher` in Java 7.

I'm aware of chosen cipher text attacks like the [Padding Oracle Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) and therefore want to add a message integrity check. In AES I just have to use the GCM mode in combination with the BouncyCastle JCE provider but I will get a:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: mac check in GCM failed
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at skc.AES256_JavaCrypto.decrypt(AES256_JavaCrypto.java:93)
    at skc.AES256_JavaCrypto.main(AES256_JavaCrypto.java:130)
```

How do I achieve a message integrity check with RSA ciphers?

Comment: Never used it, but probably http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html is what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome on Security SE. Your question seems merely related to software programming and may therefore find more pertinent answers on [so] which is dedicated to such topic.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Thx, for your reply. How can I migrate the question to stackoverflow?

Comment: This question and all associated answers can be migrated automatically as soon as enough other people from the community voted for the migration (it requires normally 5 votes from users with enough reputation). Otherwise since the question here has no answer yet, you can as well delete it here and recreate it on [so], this will cause no trouble (do not forget to delete it here to avoid duplicates though).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf To be honest, sometimes it is hard to know the appropriate place to ask a given question. What we talked about for example yesterday could be migrated to Unix/Linux users, to SuperUser ... I mean the boundaries are not very clear for certain issues such as this one. Regards

Comment: @begueradj: Yes, I know, that's why several votes are needed and sometimes a few discussions in comments or [meta]. This very situation could lead to different questions either on-topic here (relation between GCM and oracle padding for instance), or on [crypto.se] (inner working of GCM for instance). However the OP currently requested answer will most likely involve some code (right method parameters, correct object initialization, etc.) based upon the used classes documentation. BTW "BouncyCastle" matches more than 4000 posts on [so], while only 56 here...

Comment: I'm not agreeing with a migration to SO for this question. The exception is only to provide a sample result for GCM while the question is a non-programming question about RSA.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: The question being "*How to ensure message integrity for RSA ciphers by using javax.crypto.Cipher*", I do not see how one may ask about how to use `javax.crypto.Cipher` in a non-programming question. If this is the case (and I do not say this isn't), then I feel that the question and title may benefit from a rephrasing.

Comment: You've got a point there, although the choice of algorithm is probably of most importance.

Comment: Are you asking, what are the methods I need to call to perform an integrity check? If that is your question, then I agree that it should be migrated to SO. On the other hand, if you're asking, what is the right way to do this - then it should not be migrated, it would be answered here. (Hint: Just use TLS.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. How does an integrity check for RSA relate to the BadPaddingException in GCM? If you also have a problem getting GCM right then you should post your code.

Comment: @ArtjomB. There's no relation between RSA and AES with GCM mode. I asked for how do I check the integrity of an RSA encrypted message like it is done with GCM for AES ciphers.

Comment: GCM provides authenticity which is different from integrity. AFAIK, there is no way to add authenticity to RSA, but only integrity checking after decryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. GCM adds an HMAC to the cipher so integrity can be proven too. The integrity check for the RSA cipher after the decryption is too late. The `Padding Oracle Attack` takes place at decryption. So the integrity must be checked right before.

Comment: You were already told [before](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/how-to-verify-the-integrity-of-rsa-encrypted-messages), that adding authenticity is not possible with asymmetric algorithms like RSA. I'm not sure what you're asking here.